# Render flask jinja form inside javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, security, flask, jinja2

Is it unsafe to render the whole jinja2 form inside javascript variable?

Lets say a route returns a form. Then this form is rendered like this inside javascript:

```
const form = {{form}};
```

And it is used multiple times inside application and sent back via ajax requests to backend.

What security problems could it cause?

And would it help instead - rendering a form inside html, hiding it and then using javascript to `.clone()` or `.cloneNode()`to reuse the form multiple times on the page?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that you must be careful with escaping characters that could break your js syntax.

The cloneNode method can work, but then you would have to go through other hoops in order to implement csrf for these forms.
Will the page only ever post a single form? Then you could pass just the csrf token to a js variable instead of the whole form.
Will the page make multiple ajaxy posts? Then you could return a new token every time and update the existing forms accordingly.